# Why do I get an error while reading fifo in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Trying to read fifo in bash. why do I get error?

```
pipe="./$1"

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $pipe
fi

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
            if "$line" == 'exit'  || "$line" == 'EXIT' ; then
                break       
            elif ["$line" == 'yes']; then
                echo "YES"
            else
                echo $line
            fi
    fi
done

echo "Reader exiting"
```

The error I get:

```
./sh.sh: line 12: [: missing `]' ./sh.sh: line 14: [HelloWorld: command not found
```

When running from other shell and print `HelloWorld`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a command for the `if` statement, and you need
spaces in the `elif` statement.

```
if "$line" == 'exit'  || "$line" == 'EXIT' ; then
    break       
elif ["$line" == 'yes']; then
```

should be

```
if [ "$line" = 'exit' ] || [ "$line" = 'EXIT' ] ; then
    break       
elif [ "$line" = 'yes' ]; then
```

A slightly cleaner option, if you don't mind bashisms:

```
if [[ $line = exit || $line = EXIT ]]; then
    break
elif [[ $line = yes ]]; then
```